# Can we create onclick popup without Javascript in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Can we create onclick popup without Javascript in CSS?

Comment: What do you understand by popup?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem a little bit more?

Comment: @Gumbo - On clicking a Link I want to open a new window with custom size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. You have to use script to wire an event handler for onlcick.

```
<a href="Somepage.html" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

and the user agent decides whether the page should be opened in a new window or tab.

If you need a new popup window with custom size you have to use

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open)

and you can't use that without script.

Comment: then can we use show something onhover without clicking using css :hover?

Comment: I highly recommend you just use javascript.  Probably a framework.  But what your asking here IS possible.  CHeck out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266929/showing-floating-div-in-a-gridview/1267290#1267290
It should provide the answer your looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, but you can create tooltips using CSS only. [It can do the trick](http://www.webcssdesign.com/demos/css_tooltip.html)  :

You set a proper markup :

```
<div id="example">
    Result :
    <a href="#" class="tooltip">
        Article 1
        <span>Article 1's Title, Article 1's description.</span>
    </a>.
</div>
```

Then style it with hover :

```
#example { 
    float:left; 
    width:400px; 
    padding:15px; 
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
}
a {
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    color:#000000; 
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:hover {
    background-color:#ffffff; 
    text-decoration:none;
} /* background-color for IE6*/

 /* hiding the tooltip*/
a.tooltip span {
    display:none; /* if you have accessibility issues, you may choose other hiding tricks*/
    padding:2px 3px; 
    margin-left:10px; 
    width:150px;
}
 /* display on hover*/
    a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; 
    position:absolute; 
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    background:#ffffff; 
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: As I said, you cannot open a pop up without javascript or using _blank. You can just make the content appear on hover. NOthing stop you from doing it with the content you see in the current pop up using the snippet I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you might be able to fake it with `<button>`, `:focus`, and some nasty positioning code.

… but this would involve extreme levels of ugly hackery.

CSS is not designed for adding interactivity to pages. It is a presentation language.

Let JavaScript handle the custom interactions, that is what it is for (but always be pragmatic about it — [progressively enhance](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)).

Answer (score 0):

U can use css to create on click popup ..
use css checked properties 
for eg

```
input:checked {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

u have to be a little tricky while using this. Use this link for better understing

http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/fulloverlay.html#

Answer (score 0):

Here's a magic solution.
You may toggle popup using **anchor id** and **CSS :target** pseudo class.
Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style here.

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
</style>
```